# Sending messages to all users with fstream

Tags: c++, shell, debian, fstream

I'm looking into how to recreate something like the linux `wall` command.

something like `echo "Hello world" | wall`

This sends a message to all user's shells.

In the directory `/dev/pts/` are several pipes for writing to users shells. So it's quite easy to do something like...

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
   std::ofstream wall("/dev/pts/2");
   wall << "hello world" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

The problem is that `/dev/pts/*` has a feed for each open shell *(pts/2, pts/3, ...)*, is there a more general way to do this, or will I have to enumerate all the feeds in `/dev/pts/` to send a message to each users from C++ code?

Note: Not using a system call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to enumerate all the fields (if you're not going to use a system call). That can be done like this:

```c++
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

template <class File>
struct lock_helper // Simple fstream manager just for convenience
{
    template<class... Us>
    lock_helper(File& file, Us&&... us)
    {
        file.close();
        file.open(std::forward<Us>(us)...);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::ofstream out;
    for (int i = 2; out; ++i)
    {
        lock_helper<std::ofstream> lock(out, std::string("/dev/pts/") + std::to_string(i));
        out << "Hello, World\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's a really elegant solution. A lot more simple then I thought.